# Resque workes in controllers but not in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have a Resque worker that only works when used from Controllers, or Observers, but not in Models. I tried running from trigger, or call the function from controller but no luck. Keeps returning

```
Resque::NoQueueError (Jobs must be placed onto a queue.):


# models/message
def notify_receiver
  Resque.enqueue(Push, {user: receiver_id, message: message}) 
end

# workers/push
class Push
  @queue = :push_queue  
  def self.perform(options={})
    Rails.logger.info "> Push Queue"
    PushNotification.new(options).publish
  end
end
```

Can anyone point out where the problem is?

Comment: Same issue, did you solved it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I've switched to Sidekiq.